# Get location of the text box cursor

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net

**Note: I am talking about the text box cursor (aka the vertical line that shows where you're typing.  Not the mouse)**

As the nice note says above, I'm trying to get the location of the text cursor as a Point so I can show a popup below it.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text box has a `GetRectFromCharacterIndex` method that you can use. For example:

```
textbox.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(textbox.CaretIndex)
```